# How to download app the was released as a alpha version?

Tags: android

I made a full roll out for alpha version.

I thought that I will get a link to download my app from play market, but I didn't. I see that there is a `Manage testers` section where I fill in my email address that corresponds to play market account on my device.

As far as I understand I need to get a mail with a link to download the app.

So, question is - when I get this mail? Am I should get it immediately or after the app will be published?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a link with the access to the app that links give you the access if your account was in the alpha list when the app is realize the link gives you the app but google always need a bit time to analyze if the app was already published it takes 2-6h if not he can take days

Comment: I did not get what you mean. You said 'So you have a link`, but as I told I didn't, this is the problem. And I need to find out when and how I should get it. According to your answer I did not understand when I get this link and how should I get it.

Comment: example link = https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netflix.mediaclient, if you are logged to the account that you have with the alpha version they will give you the link but they check if your account is for alpha or not